# automatically run %matplotlib inline in jupyter qtconsole

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, qtconsole

Is there a way to change the config file to make jupyter qtconsole run the following command on startup?:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this line to the `ipython_config.py` file (**not** the `ipython_qtconsole_config.py` file):

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
```

Comment: Awesome. I was unaware of all the customization that could be done with the ipython_config.py file... If anyone else doesn't already have that file, run `ipython profile create`.

Answer (score 4):

In your `ipython_config.py` file you can specify commands to run at startup (including magic % commands) by setting `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines`. For example,

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = """
%matplotlib inline
%autoreload 2
import your_favorite_module
""".split('\n')
```

Comment: The `ipython_config.py` is, by default, under `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/` according to the documentation http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/config.html

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`, and

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.code_to_run = ''
```

==>

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.code_to_run = '%pylab inline'
```